# Dynamic OrderBy CriteriaBuilder without Switch statement

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following code snippet below. The only difference between the two switch blocks is the fact that I'm calling `criteriaBuilder.asc` vs `criteriaBuilder.desc`. Is there a way I can avoid a switch statement or an if statement and call the proper criteriaBuilder "sortdirection" method dynamically?

```
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
Root<Cases> caseRoot = criteria.from(Cases.class);

switch (sortDirection) {
    case "asc":
        switch (orderBy) {
            case 0:
                criteria.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(caseRoot.get(Cases_.caseid)));
                break;
            case 1:
                criteria.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(caseRoot.get(Cases_.dtype)));
                break;
            case 2:
                criteria.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(caseRoot.get(Cases_.title)));
                break;
        }
        break;
    case "desc":
        switch (orderBy) {
            case 0:
                criteria.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(caseRoot.get(Cases_.caseid)));
                break;
            case 1:
                criteria.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(caseRoot.get(Cases_.dtype)));
                break;
            case 2:
                criteria.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(caseRoot.get(Cases_.title)));
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

E.g. Below is completely made up code, but hopefully it gives an idea as to what I mean.

```
sortDirectionMethod = criteriaBuilder.asc; // Somehow store the criteriaBuilder method of either asc or desc.
switch (orderBy) {
    case 0:
        criteria.orderBy(sortDirectionMethod(caseRoot.get(Cases_.caseid)));
        break;
    case 1:
        criteria.orderBy(sortDirectionMethod(caseRoot.get(Cases_.dtype)));
        break;
    case 2:
        criteria.orderBy(sortDirectionMethod(caseRoot.get(Cases_.title)));
        break;
}
break;
```

Comment: Use `enum` instead of `switch`

Answer (score 0):

Try `enume` like this:

```java
public enum OrderBy {
caseid(0), dtype(1), title(2);

private int type;

public OrderBy(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}

}

//then instead of using switch you can use enum like this:

OrderBy orderByEnum = OrderBy.valueOf(orderBy);
criteria.orderBy("asc".equals(sortDirection) ? criteria.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(orderByEnum.name()) : 
criteria.orderBy(criteriaBuilder. desc(orderByEnum.name()));
```

Comment: The integers are columns numbers that are coming in from the view from the web interface side of things from a table. Thus, caseid, dtype, title may have different column numbers for each table. So unfortunately, an enum won't work for my scenario.

Comment: You still write your switch case right? That means you already know what integer will pass into the code, why enum not working? The column name is the same, you must design the table first, you already know all the details. Plus you can put column name as a field in the ENUM, make it changeable among different entities.